# How to use filter-based feature selection for mixed data types?

Tags: anova, python, feature-selection, scikit-learn, mixed-type-data

The idea behind filter-based methods of feature selection is that we assign a value to each feature, where the value indicates how important the feature is for predicting the outcome variable. We can then order the features based on its values and select k best features. We can do this using the SelectKBest method in Python and pass a feature selection method that assigns the importance values.

Features (independent variables) can be continuous or categorical and outcomes (dependent variable) can also be continuous or categorical. There are many different methods for selecting features, each of which is suitable for specific types of features and outcomes.

**The question is:** How can filter-based methods be used when features are of mixed data type, eg., some features are numeric (continuous) and others categorical (eg., binary) and the output variable is categorical.
Is it okay to use e.g. the Python method f_classif (ANOVA) and compare the p-values for the different feature types to select the best features?